# How to add a button to the bottom of a static table view in storyboard

Tags: ios

I try to add a custom button programmed. However, if I have a static table view in storyboard, how can I add a button at the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Made the topic more concise and improved the spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another `UIViewController` in which you add a `Container View` linked to your table view. Besides that container view you may add any other controls (eg. UIButton).

Answer (score 0):

You Must have any parent UIView there in which you have added STATIC UITableView, 
You can just need to assign negative position (X and Y ) for that parent view, So that parent UIView will get slide upside.

Now you can view the bottom so you can add what ever you want, Once you finish adding your controls, reset (X and Y) to 0 as before.

Hope this will help you, :)

Ajay Mahajan